# TeamCity pass EnviromentName to Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, teamcity

Asp.Net Core 2.2.0
In TeamCity I have a build step to run integration-tests in my Asp.Net Core application.

I need to pass a value for IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName

How to do this ?

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // do something with env.EnvironmentName
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Team City reads the environment variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/project-and-agent-level-build-parameters.html#ProjectandAgentLevelBuildParameters-AgentLevelBuildParameters) from the `buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties` file on your agent machine. You can add a line like this in the end of the file.

```
env.EnvironmentName=Testing
```

And restart the agent

Comment: I'm not trying to associate a particular environment with a particular build-agent.  I'm trying to associate a particular environment with a particular job -- irrelevant of the agent it runs on.  Actually I only have a single build-agent and it must build-test my app for various environments ( CI SIT etc )